# exporting a specific row from CSV using csvsimple

Tags: csv, csvsimple

What is the best way to obtain a specific row (or a subset of row) when I use `csvsimple`?

`⧵csvreader[head to column names]{filename.csv}{}{}`

For example, I would like to get only row three from the `filename.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\csvreader[head to column names, filter test = \ifnumequal{\thecsvinputline}{x},]
```

where `x` denotes the integer number of a particular row.